# calculating quantity and price and subtotal in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am developing simple invoice in php, i come up with this result, i cant do calculation of price by multiplying rate and quantity and showing result automatically on total input field, where to start and i am using html table in form tag.

```js
$(function() {

     // jQuery methods go here...

  $('#itemquantity').change(function() {
    var total = 0.0;

    $("#itemprice").each(function() {
      var quantity = $('#itemquantity').val();
      var rate = $('#itemrate').val();
      total = quantity * rate;
      $('#itemprice').text('' + total);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="inventory" id="inventory">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Item</span></th>
      <th><span>Description</span></th>
      <th><span>Rate</span></th>
      <th><span>Quantity</span></th>
      <th><span>Price</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="items" name="item"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="items" name="itemdesc"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="items" name="itemrate" id="itemrate"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="itemquantity" class="items" name="itemquantity" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="itemprice" id="price" class="items" name="itemprice"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the value in Rate input and Quantity should automatically be multiplied and shown in the price Field

Comment: why are you using `$("#itemprice").each(function() {`? your selector will only select one element here

Answer (score 0):

it's a type problem.

You have to add parseFloat (if they are float) or parseInt to the value, as following :

```
 var quantity = parseFloat($('#itemquantity').val());
  var rate = parseFloat($('#itemrate').val());
  total = quantity * rate;
```

source : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

Answer (score 0):

You were using `jQuery.each` on a single selected element without using its parameter.

As far as I understood, you need to bind the value of *price* to the *quantity* and *rate*. So that if either quantity or rate is changed, the appropriate value for price must be calculated and displayed.

You can make a function for calculating price, and bind it to its dependent factors.

```js
$(function() {
    // jQuery methods go here...
    $('#itemquantity').on("change", function() {
        calculatePrice();
    });
    $('#itemrate').on("change", function() {
        calculatePrice();
    });

    function calculatePrice(){
        var quantity = $('#itemquantity').val();
        var rate = $('#itemrate').val();
        if(quantity != "" && rate != ""){
            var price = quantity * rate;
        }
        $('#itemprice').val(price.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="inventory" id="inventory">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><span>Item</span></th>
      <th><span>Description</span></th>
      <th><span>Rate</span></th>
      <th><span>Quantity</span></th>
      <th><span>Price</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="items" name="item"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="items" name="itemdesc"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="items" name="itemrate" id="itemrate"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="itemquantity" class="items" name="itemquantity" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="itemprice" id="price" class="items" name="itemprice"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```